# line color using CGContextStrokePath

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I am trying to draw to lines each with a different color. (but connected)   If I don't add and stroke the second line the color is red, but the moment I add the second line the whole thing is yellow.  How can I have two lines show with different colors?  my code is below.

```
    CGPoint FirstCGPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:cr.points[0]];
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, FirstCGPoint.x, FirstCGPoint.y);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
    CGPoint SecondCGPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:cr.points[1]];
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, SecondCGPoint.x, SecondCGPoint.y);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor]);
    CGPoint NewFirstCGPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:cr.points[3]];
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, NewFirstCGPoint.x, NewFirstCGPoint.y);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using paths?

Comment: It's on a map view using coordinates.  I've been just trying to simplify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it, you needn't to use path.

```
CGPoint FirstCGPoint = CGPointMake(10.0f, 40.0f) ;
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, FirstCGPoint.x, FirstCGPoint.y) ;
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
CGPoint SecondCGPoint = CGPointMake(10.0f, 100.0f) ;
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, SecondCGPoint.x, SecondCGPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor]);
CGPoint NewFirstCGPoint = CGPointMake(100.0f, 100.0f) ;
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, SecondCGPoint.x, SecondCGPoint.y) ;
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, NewFirstCGPoint.x, NewFirstCGPoint.y) ;
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: This also makes sense.  What the difference when one doesn't use a path and skips it altogether?

Comment: Do you create your path by using `CGPathCreateMutable` method? It is for reusing. Once created and constructed, you can keep it and use it later.

Answer (score 1):

For the second line, you have to start a *new path* (from the second to the third point).

If you just *append* a new segment to the first path, the entire path will be
stroked in the new color (yellow).

Comment: I see. That does make sense.  Would I just use CGPathCreateMutable again?

Comment: @jdross: Yes. Alternatively, use CGContextBeginPath(), CGContextMoveToPoint(), CGContextAddLineToPoint(), CGContextStrokePath() for each line. Then you don't have to create a (mutable) path.

Answer (score 1):

check one time below code.. may this help you

First of all take global array and add different UIColor to it as per your requirement

Add this code to viewDIdLoad

```
array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],[UIColor greenColor],[UIColor yellowColor], nil];
```

take another global variable for `int` type try to set it value by incriment or decrement or assign a value to it

then use the code like this in place of  `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);`

like this..

```
UIColor *colo=(UIColor*)[array objectAtIndex:1];
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
                                 colo.CGColor);
```

NOTE: in array i had used int.1 in at objectAtIndex in array.At that place put you selected index which is incremented or decremented or assigned index to it

if you wand to set different red,green and blue  and saturation values.
Then in .h declare

```
CGFloat red;
CGFloat green;
CGFloat blue;
CGFloat opacity;
```

and in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
red = 0.0/255.0;
green = 0.0/255.0;
blue = 0.0/255.0;
brush = 10.0;
opacity = 1.0;

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

for different color set the different float value as per your selection color
and use like this in context

```
 CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, opacity);
```

May this code help you .Happy coding